# tortoisegitのhooksが実行されない。

Tags: tortoisegit

●目的
tortoisegit hooksのprepare-commit-msgを実行したい。

●試したこと
リポジトリ.git\hooks内に「prepare-commit-msg.sample」が存在したため、ファイル名から.sampleを削除し「prepare-commit-msg」にリネーム。コミットしたところ、「prepare-commit-msg」が実行されているような形跡はなかった。

まずはサンプルでも構わないためprepare-commit-msgを実行したいと考えているのですが何が原因かご教授いただきたいです。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.git/hooks/` に用意されているスクリプトは、いわゆる Linux 環境向けのシェルスクリプトなので、Windows 環境であるなら Git Bash などのコマンド環境で使わないと恐らくうまく機能しません。

TortoiseGit でフックスクリプトを利用するには、リポジトリをエクスプローラで開いた状態で右クリック → 「TortoiseGit」 → 「設定」を開き、表示されたダイアログから「フックスクリプト」で登録する必要がありそうです。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

**参考:**
[クライアント側フックスクリプト | TortoiseGit マニュアル - Qiita](https://qiita.com/MakotoIshikawa/items/db67029bd65291e75d89#%E3%82%AF%E3%83%A9%E3%82%A4%E3%82%A2%E3%83%B3%E3%83%88%E5%81%B4%E3%83%95%E3%83%83%E3%82%AF%E3%82%B9%E3%82%AF%E3%83%AA%E3%83%97%E3%83%88)